# Returning a page template without diazo

Tags: plone

Running: Plone 5.0.0 with Diazo.

How does one permanently bypass the diazo theme applying in BrowserView templates?  (Not with the diazo.off=1)

Example:
I have a diazo theme.  I have a template that I'm returning via a BrowserView's ViewPageTemplateFile:

```
class ExhibitView(BrowserView):

    template = ViewPageTemplateFile("exhibit.pt")

    def __call__(self):
        return self.template()
```

The exhibit.pt file is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
  xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
  xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
  i18n:domain="plone"
  lang="en">
<body>
    Is it just this text?
</body>
</html>
```

I removed the plone master template, it is still applying the diazo rules.  I just want it to return a barebone template, unthemed by diazo.  We used to be able to do that before Diazo as I shown above.

Also making a Diazo rule to skip this is out of the question because it has to be installed in many places, I don't want to apply rules to everyone's site themes to make this work.  That is hacky.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this line:

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.theming/blob/5ba9447150776f7edbfd73b528b9b62f31dd14b5/src/plone/app/theming/policy.py#L79

If you have an header called 'X-Theme-Disabled' the transform is not applied. Two lines later you see the condition that is checking for "diazo.off".

So you should modify your __call__ method in a way that it sets the header before returning the template.
Something line this:

```
def __call__(self):
    self.request.response.setHeader('X-Theme-Disabled', '1')
    return self.template()
```

The control panel is doing the same:

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.theming/blob/fbbdc3bfdbccf2315cef069fe827fea863feb1c8/src/plone/app/theming/browser/controlpanel.py#L72

Caveat: I did not tested this  :)

Comment: Great! I am going to add this to the documentation.